# Facebook Like button in Page Tab App

Tags: php, html, facebook

I've seem to have run into an issue here.
I have a voting/gallery app on a Tab of a specific page on Facebook.

So to provide a user with a direct link to a image in a Gallery(in the Paget Tab App), i generated a URL with APP_DATA, so I can pass data(image filename)to the `iframe`.
So basically my links look kinda like this:

> https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx?sk=app_xxxxxxx&app_data=showimage.php%3Ffilename%3D1336314789stevakralj%2Ejpg

Now, when I try to create a Like button for this Link, I get nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem... In my app, which is hosted by a page tab, the "Like" buttons for each item apper correctly and the "data-href" attribute for each "like" button has the same format as yours, but EVERY like button points to the Facebook page which hosts the app, not to the individual item... so, for every item in my gallery, the "like" information under it is exactly the same (number of likes for the page hosting the app) and if I "dislike" any item, I "dislike" the entire page.
I have tried the same format but the parameter NOT on a facebook page... then it works... I don't see a difference but:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx?sk=app_xxxxxxx&app_data=abc (DOESN'T WORK, for each item which have app_data different)
https://www.mytestweb.com/test.aspx?sk=app_xxxxxxx&app_data=abc (WORKS for each item which have app_data different)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't seem to allow linking directly to a tab page so strips your app ID from the URL. There's no way to get around this except by linking to an external site that bounces back to Facebook.